# Convert string with substrings into list of objects in correct order

Tags: c#, string, list, parsing, data-manipulation

Okay, I have a kind of complex string list that I need to convert to a new output. I feel like I may have gone about it the wrong way, or maybe its just that complicated? It will do the most of it alright, but then once it finishes the third loop and goes back to the second loop it adds an empty object and the third object again and errors. Is there another way to do this or fix what I have?

Any help or idea's would be amazing :(

**Note**: Names inside string changed for privacy, they are not normally string1, etc.

```
(String1, string2, string3, string4(string5, string6, string7(c1, c2, c3)), string8)

TO

- string1
- string2
- string3
- string4
  - string5
  - string6
  - string7
    - c1
    - c2
    - c3
-string8
```

**My Code**

```
 public List<object> ParseOutput(string parseString) {
    List<object> sortedList = new List<object>();

    int indexFirstLoop = 0;
    int indexSecondLoop = 0;
    int indexThirdLoop = 0;
    int stringLength = parseString.Length - 1;

    //Iternate through string to find comma seperated words
    for (int a = 0; a < parseString.Length; a++)
        {
            //Hits a comma, take word before comma and add to array
            if(parseString[a] == ','){
                //get word before comma and put into array
                sortedList.Add(parseString.Substring(indexFirstLoop, a - indexFirstLoop).Trim());
                indexFirstLoop = a + 1;
            }
            //If hits open parenthesis then go to next section and loop through those strings
            else if(parseString[a] == '('){
                var secondString = parseString.Substring(a + 1, stringLength - a);
                var secondList = new List<string>();
                //Second Loop
                for (int b = 0; b < secondString.Length; b++)
                {
                    //Hits a comma, take word before comma and add to array
                    if(secondString[b] != ')'){
                        if(secondString[b] == ','){
                            secondList.Add(secondString.Substring(indexSecondLoop, b - indexSecondLoop).Trim());
                            indexSecondLoop = b + 1;
                        }
                    
                    //If hits open parenthesis inside first parentethsis, then go to next section and loop through those strings
                    else if(parseString[b] == '('){
                        var secondStringLength = secondString.Length;
                        var thirdString = secondString.Substring(b + 2, secondStringLength - (b + 2));
                        var thirdList = new List<string>();
                        //Third Loop
                        for (int c = 0; c < thirdString.Length; c++)
                        {
                            //Hits a comma, take word before comma and add to array
                            if(thirdString[c] == ','){
                                thirdList.Add(thirdString.Substring(indexThirdLoop, c - indexThirdLoop).Trim());
                                indexThirdLoop = c + 1;
                            }
                        } //End Last Loop
                        if(thirdList.Count > 0){
                            sortedList.Add(thirdList);
                        }
                    } //End Second Parenthesis Loop
                    }
                }//End Second Loop

                if(secondList.Count > 0){
                    sortedList.Add(secondList);
                }

            } //End First Parenthesis Loop
        } //End First Loop

    return sortedList;
}
```

Comment: what is the goal here? which object or output do you expect to get?